# email address is already registered

Tags: support, jobs

I log in to the careers site using openid (blogger if that matters). I then try to "register user" and get

> email is already registered

message.

If I try to request an invite, I get

> An invitation request has already been made for this email address.

To be honest, I don't remember if I requested before (but this would have been weeks ago).

If I Log out, I get a message that I'm already a registered user.

Is this perhaps tied to the openid authentication problem from other posts? If not, how do I know what the decision is on my request to create a profile?

Also - if this helps - I got error id `bX-pzae8c` at one point when trying to log in as well.

Update: Logged out and back on this morning using blogger openid and received bX-pzae8c again. Additional information provided on the error screen shows

host: www.blogger.com
uri: /openid-confirm.g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there are a few things going on.

1. you had another account using gmail for authentication. I've merged this one with the account that uses blogger. You can still use gmail to sign in in addition to blogger (see below though).
2. I was able to reproduce the error you get signing in with blogger, but it happens on blogger's end. We'll look in to this, and will update answer. **Edit** This is an issue on blogger's end and is affecting other people as well. As long as you're logged in to blogger openID will work, if you're logged out it won't. [There are two threads on this](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/search.py?hl=en&forum=1&query=bX-wsr3k8), but there doesn't seem to be an official response - your best bet is to take this up with them.
3. I sent you an invite.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm in now. Didn't realize I also had google authentication. I'll avoid using blogger openid from now on. I appreciate your help !